# Why could I only request the index.htm when I had run a yarn serve at local. I could not request other file,

Tags: javascript, hadoop-yarn, serve

I'm learning about GitLab ci. There is my pipeline code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfn3k.png)

There was the result. I have already ensured all the variables are right.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOPT8.png)

There is my root directory
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci9rX.png)

I guess there must be the yarn serve default configuration

I just started the serve. There is nothing change. Maybe someone can tell me why.

```yaml
stages:
    - build
    - test
    - deploy staging
    - deploy production

variables:
    APP_VERSION: $CI_PIPELINE_IID
    VERSION_PATH: version.html

build website:
    image: node:16-alpine
    stage: build
    script:
        - yarn install
        - yarn lint
        - yarn test
        - yarn build
        - echo $APP_VERSION > build/version.html
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - build

test index:
    image: node:16-alpine
    stage: test
    script:
        - yarn global add serve
        - apk add curl
        - serve -s build &
        - sleep 10
        - curl http://localhost:3000 | grep 'React App'
#        - curl http://localhost:3000/$VERSION_PATH | grep $APP_VERSION
```

Comment: First of all, write code here don't post images., and second where did version.html come from? you are probably doing them both in test stages, and they probably are running in parallel, but nothing much can be said, show the entire configuration for GitLab CI, only then you might get some answers.

Comment: I have added the entire configuration for GitLab CI, please. @Ace

Comment: If it worked for you you can accept the answer, so others can find it.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with GitLab CI configuration, you are doing everything as should be you have clearly defined the stages, the problem however is you are using

```
serve -s build
```

the `-s` option is made for serving single-page applications, that is it will always return the `index.html` on each request, it will not return any other page, so your version.html will not get served.

Change it from `serve -s build` to

```
serve build
```

as you can see when I made a request to `version.html` it gave me a `301` status and redirected me to `/version`

[image]

however, when I run it without the `-s` option it returns multiple pages ( status 200)

[image]

so run `serve` without `-s` option

Comment: wow！！！I'm trying